# Upload error in Launchpad - source file already exists

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad

```
DEBUG Considering changefile 73927/ubuntu/brightness-controller_2.3.4-0~202004250741~ubuntu20.04.1_source.changes
DEBUG Finding fresh policy
INFO Processing upload brightness-controller_2.3.4-0~202004250741~ubuntu20.04.1_source.changes
INFO Upload was rejected:
INFO    File brightness-controller_2.3.4-0~202004250741~ubuntu20.04.1.tar.xz already exists in Brightness Controller, but uploaded version has different contents. See more information about this error in https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/UploadErrors.
INFO    Files specified in DSC are broken or missing, skipping package unpack verification.
INFO Committing the transaction and any mails associated with this upload.
```

I imported the code from the GitHub repository and tried to package it for focal and groovy using source packaging recepies in Launchpad. The package build successfully for groovy, but showed this error for focal.

I have done this quite a few times to make packages in PPA.
How to fix this, and why did this occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have this version in [your PPA](https://launchpad.net/~apandada1/+archive/ubuntu/brightness-controller?field.series_filter=focal).

So you need to change it to something like *2.3.4-0~202004250741~ubuntu20.04.1ppa1* and upload.